# Is this activities count in lust/sin or not ? I mean he/she will get paap or not?

Tags: sin

suppose if someone is not married .If  he is doing sex with many girls ( call girl, prostitute) or if she is  doing sex with many boy's( play boy)

Is  this  activities count in lust/sin ?  I mean he/she  will  get paap or not ?

I know that  this  is  sin  for married person . But  here im confused  about  unmarried person.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

athedānīṁ pratiṣiddha-lakṣaṇasyādharmasya tathaiva kartuḥ śraddhāyā vaisādṛśyāt karma-phalaṁ visadṛśaṁ bhavati

Just as by executing various pious activities one achieves different positions in heavenly life, by acting impiously one achieves different positions in hellish life.

In Srimad Bhagavatam 5.25.20 its said as:-

yas tv iha vā agamyāṁ striyam agamyaṁ vā puruṣaṁ yoṣid abhigacchati tāv amutra kaśayā tāḍayantas tigmayā sūrmyā lohamayyā puruṣam āliṅgayanti striyaṁ ca puruṣa-rūpayā sūrmyā

A man or woman who indulges in sexual intercourse with an unworthy member of the opposite sex is punished after death by the assistants of Yamarāja in the hell known as Taptasūrmi. There such men and women are beaten with whips. The man is forced to embrace a red-hot iron form of a woman, and the woman is forced to embrace a similar form of a man. Such is the punishment for illicit sex.

"Generally a man should not have sexual relations with any woman other than his wife. According to Vedic principles, the wife of another man is considered one’s mother, and sexual relations are strictly forbidden with one’s mother, sister and daughter. If one indulges in illicit sexual relations with another man’s wife, that activity is considered identical with having sex with one’s mother. This act is most sinful. The same principle holds for a woman also; if she enjoys sex with a man other than her husband, the act is tantamount to having sexual relations with her father or son. Illicit sex life is always forbidden, and any man or woman who indulges in it is punished in the manner described in this verse."

From Srimad Bhagavatm, translation and commentary by A.C.Bhakti Vedanta Swami Srila Prabhupad.

[image]